# Как удалить запись в таблице по истечении времени

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

Допустим, я хочу удалять записи из бд автоматически, у которых истек срок времени. Как это можно сделать на стороне MS SQL или ASP?

Comment: Как удобнее/проще, так и делайте. [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16). Популярны библиотеки [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) и [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). Можно и просто [таймер](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/19.8.php) применить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Благодарю вас за ответ.